# Datastore persistence is one behind

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have the following very simple code to persist strings in the `datastore`. I have pulled it together from various `datastore` examples but I am still not happy with it.

Its aim is simply to store a string under a key in `persist` and retrieve it under `fromPresistence`.

```
// Used to store the string value.
type Entity struct {
    Value string
}

// Grow my key.
func key(x string) *datastore.Key {
    return datastore.NewKey(context, "Persist", x, 0, nil)
}

// Get it from persistence storage.
func fromPersistence(x string) string {
    var persisted string = x
    // Make my key.
    k := key(x)
    // New entity for filling in.
    e := new(Entity)
    // Look it up!
    if err := datastore.Get(context, k, e); err == nil {
        // It was there!
        persisted = e.Value
        context.Debugf("Persisted %s=%s", x, persisted)
    }

    return persisted
}

// Persist the latest number.
func persist(x string) func(*big.Int) {
    return func(n *big.Int) {
        // Make my key.
        k := key(x)
        // New entity for filling in.
        e := new(Entity)
        // Value is the decimal form of the number.
        e.Value = n.String()
        context.Debugf("Persist %s=%s", start, e.Value)
        if _, err := datastore.Put(context, k, e); err != nil {
            context.Debugf("Persist failed! %s", err)
        }
    }
}
```

but it seems to be behind by one each time. Here's some log results:

```
C:\Go\GAE\go_appengine\google\src>\go\gae\go_appengine\dev_appserver.py unique/
INFO     2013-10-15 20:55:08,296 sdk_update_checker.py:245] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-10-15 20:55:09,726 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:50218
INFO     2013-10-15 20:55:09,746 dispatcher.py:168] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-10-15 20:55:09,763 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2013-10-15 20:56:22,131 module.py:599] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2013-10-15 20:56:22,344 module.py:599] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2013-10-15 20:56:22,448 module.py:599] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2013/10/15 20:56:26 DEBUG: Persisted 38913371956013078496870267859=3378577588146889866220112993
2013/10/15 20:56:26 DEBUG: Persist 38913371956013078496870267859=21186844412818184262771263024
...
2013/10/15 20:56:30 DEBUG: Persist 38913371956013078496870267859=1324177775801136516423203939
INFO     2013-10-15 20:56:30,756 module.py:599] default: "GET /n HTTP/1.1" 200 19
INFO     2013-10-15 20:56:30,927 module.py:599] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2013/10/15 20:56:32 DEBUG: Persist 38913371956013078496870267859=20778614526287997725322370609

C:\Go\GAE\go_appengine\google\src>\go\gae\go_appengine\dev_appserver.py unique/
INFO     2013-10-15 20:57:15,657 sdk_update_checker.py:245] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-10-15 20:57:17,033 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:50241
INFO     2013-10-15 20:57:17,085 dispatcher.py:168] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-10-15 20:57:17,098 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
2013/10/15 20:57:24 DEBUG: Persisted 38913371956013078496870267859=1324177775801136516423203939
2013/10/15 20:57:24 DEBUG: Persist 38913371956013078496870267859=20778614526287997725322370609
...
```

See how the last attempt at persistence stores *20778614526287997725322370609* but the retrieval attempt returned the previously persisted value of *1324177775801136516423203939*.

What am I doing wrong?

**NB:** I have changed the code to use the `context.Debugf` mechanism to print my debug strings to get the strange log records out of the equation.

The old `Logf` code was as follows. I am sure it was the cause of the strange log entries. It is not the target of my question. I will fix this myself.

```
func Logf(format string, a ...interface{}) {
    if context != nil {
        // Context is valid.
        if len(logQueue) > 0 {
            // Roll out the stored entries.
            for i := 0; i < len(logQueue); i++ {
                context.Debugf("%s", logQueue[i])
            }
            // Empty the queue.
            logQueue = make([]string, 0)
        }
        // Pass a "" to just flush the queue
        if format != "" {
            // Log it through the context.
            context.Debugf(format, a)
        }
    } else {
        // No context! Queue it up.
        logQueue = append(logQueue, fmt.Sprintf(format, a...))
    }

}
```

Comment: Those aren't the same print statements.  There are no "[ ]"

Comment: I know this sounds like a dumb question, but are you using `1` based indexing anywhere? This just *feels* like it's pulling the wrong value from the slice, and that the index is off by one. Maybe in the `NewKey` function?

Comment: I plan to post my `Logf` function later to dispel the thought that there are slices/arrays happening here. I am confident that the formatting and `MISSING` annotations are purely a red herring. Note that the key is always `x string` and the value returned is always a `string`.

Comment: @Intermernet - I don't think this is an off-by-one issue - but obviously I may be wrong. This is just my attempt at a simple Key/Value storage using the GAE `datastore` system.

Comment: @Intermernet - Question edited to get the logging issue out of the picture. Sorry for the distraction.

Answer (score 0):

There's a <strike>good</strike> chance here that you're seeing is one of those unexpected aspects of distributed systems. If your calls to `persist` and `fromPersistence` end up running on different instances of your application, the log messages may be taking slightly different paths to where they persist. Note that the timestamps on the seemingly-reversed log messages are the same.

Comment: The `Logf` system may delay the actual logging of the record until a `Context` is available to log against. The time stamps are not therefore reliable. Interesting idea though. I suspect, however, that this is not a timing issue - the lag occurs every time, consistently.

Comment: I have now confirmed that the same issue happens on the live site - not just in the local emulator. I don't think I am seeing different threads/instances - I would expect that would show only occasionally, I am seeing it **every** time.

Answer (score 0):

look at your datastore code... it's somehow storing the values in with the keys.

the statement

`Logf("Persist %s=%s", x, e.Value)`

is producing:

`2013/10/13 23:21:26 DEBUG: Persist [38913371956013078496870267859 19124562091635092830747528895]=%s(MISSING)`

which means your 'x' value there is a slice of the key and some other value (from your text it would seem it's the previous key value).

the actual value is missing... that's what the `%s(MISSING)` bit means

Comment: A good point but I reasoned that the ...MISSING stuff was just my lack of familiarity with `fmt`. The functions work correctly - the only problem is that there is consistently a one-entry lag. The fact that the logging for both `Persist` and `Persisted` is the same suggests that it could even be my logging mechanism at fault.

Comment: I'd correct the logging system so you're getting reliable answers from it before relying on it to diagnose another part of the system.
It's really hard to see where your one-entry lag is coming from when the logging function you're reporting it with is so broken... your assurances that 'it's working right' when it so clearly isn't are kinda dubious ;)

Comment: Just to clarify: what's actually in e.Value for each of these cases? Your log functions are saying it's MISSING, and your key values returned are string slices. It's hard to see what's going on when the information available is so garbled ;)  
Have you written any test cases for this functionality?